# Plot Excel Secondary Axis

Tags: excel, plot

I recently switched to a Mac and am trying to plot a chart with 2 secondary Y Axis.

My table looks like this.

```
 Price   CPU   Memory
 0.2      2     8
 0.4      4     16
 0.88     8     32
 1.247    16    64
```

I would just like to plot a simple line graph with "Price" on the x-axis and "CPU" and "Memory" on the y-axis. How do I do this on Mac Excel 2015?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macexcel/secondary-axis-in-excel-for-mac-2016/da9a62b5-1afc-40d4-b08e-3fb844fa608e?auth=1) for 2016 says

> click on the data series so that it highlights - shows data points.
>   right click and select format data series choose secondary axis

Might work in 2015